# How to generate <a> list from published layers in Geoserver?

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers-3, geoserver, wms

I am building a webmapping app. I parse the WMS request to have the title of each layer in `layers`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8082/geoserver/wms?service=wms&request=GetCapabilities', true);
        xhr.onload = function() {
            var parser = new ol.format.WMSCapabilities();
            var capabilities = parser.read(xhr.responseText);
            var layers = capabilities.Capability.Layer.Layer.Title; 
};
```

But then I fail to access to the titles contain in `layers`:

```
$.each(layers, function(i)
            {
                var list = $('</br><a/>')
                .text(layers[i])
                .appendTo($('div.myDiv'));
            });
```

What did I miss? Thanx for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is, that you need the **Name** of the Layer, not the **Title** to be able to call it.

So you would parse the capabilities like this:

```
var layers = capabilities.Capability.Layer.Layer.Name;
```